# Parent div expand with children Div

Tags: css, html, height, parent

I need to keep the height of the box the same as the height of the image. When the kitten (example) image is 398px height, the div shall have the same height.
The Problem is, that the other children div, inside the .item div expand the parent div with approx. 150px.

How can I stop this behaviour?
I tried several other methids like overflow:hidden/auto etc. but nothing worked fine.
Need help please! :)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/398/398" />
        <div class="box">
            <span id="header-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="headlineblog"><h1>Headline</h1></div>
        <div class="cat"><h2>Category</h2></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**:

```
#container {}
.item {width: 398px;float:left;margin: 10px;overflow: hidden !important;}
.item > img {width: 398px !important}
.item .box {background-color: white;
margin: 10px;
height: 65px;
position: relative;
top: -110px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #BBBDBE;
min-height: 65px;
padding: 10px;
width: 358px;

}
.cat {position: relative;left: 280px;bottom: 230px;}
.cat h2 a{font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 300;color: #FF6400}
.headlineblog {position: relative;left: 20px;bottom: 195px;}
.headlineblog h1 a{font-size: 18px; color: black; font-weight: 700}
.item .box #header-content { position: absolute; bottom: 10px;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 300;color: grey;width: 310px;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap; }​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Df73h/4/)

Comment: You should include the code here as well as linking to jsFiddle.  Same goes for any third party site.  If jsFiddle disappears in a few years time, this question will not help people in the future.

Comment: +1 for listening to the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `.item` to have `position: relative`, and the necessary children to have `position: absolute`, adjusting their top/bottom positioning a bit.

- http://jsfiddle.net/aK4vy/

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I missed something, but I would do it this way:

Give the parent container which is in this case `div.item` a position attribute of `position: relative;`

Now you can position the 'white-box' within your parent container with a position attribute of `position: absolute;` To position it at the bottom of the parent container use `bottom: 5px;` (or another number that suits you) If you want the white box to be at the top you would use something like `top: 5px;`

I don't see a reason to position the elements within the 'white-box' in an absolute fashion. Using floats is a lot clearer in my opinon. Anyway, here is the code:

markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/398/398">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="top">
                <span class="headlineblog"><h1>Headline</h1></span>
                <span class="cat"><h2>Category</h2></span>                
            </div>
            <span class="header-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

styles:

```
#container {}

.item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
.item img { 
    width: 398px;
}

.item .box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;    
    height: 65px;
    width: 358px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;    
}

.item .box .top {
    /* clear the floating elements */
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.item .box .headlineblog {
    float: left;
}

.item .box .cat {
    float: right;
}

​.​item .box .header-content {
    color: grey;
}​
```

jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7fJ6e/1/)

If this is not an option for you please describe why.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your solution. This is not the option, because the "<div class="box">" div is the dynamic content, we're getting straight outta Magento. Therefore it's seperated. .headlingeblog and .cat are coming after the blog, as you can see in my code. 
Your solution might be good and working fine, so thank you for your afford!!